# Array elements to digits

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array, which contains integers. I would like to separate each array elements to its digits, so I can take conditions to each digits. How can I do this separation?

```
Sub numberstodigits()
    Dim myArray
    myArray = Array(586, 453, 123, 456)
    '~~> ex.: 586 should be separated to 5, 8, 6
End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you running into exactly? We're not here to write code for you.

Comment: Use the a `For Each` loop on the array, and then another `For Each` using the `Mid` function on each array element identify the individual digits in each value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub numberstodigits()
    Dim myArray, digits As String
    myArray = Array(586, 453, 123, 456)
    digits = ""
    For Each a In myArray
        For i = 1 To Len(a)
            digits = digits & "," & Mid(a, i, 1)
        Next i
    Next a
    digits = Mid(digits, 2)
    MsgBox digits
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

another method:

```
Sub M_snb()
  For Each it In Array(586, 453, 123, 456)
   sn = Split(StrConv(it, 64), Chr(0))
'  MsgBox Join(sn, vbLf)
  Next
End Sub
```